# Error assert en pytest

Tags: python

Estoy intentando ejecutar un método `get`, pasandole un `jsonschema` en `pytest`. La cuestión es que el método está correcto, pero me tira un `400`.

El código sería este:

```py
import json
import requests
import jsonschema
class TestIdentifyById:
    def get_test_identify_by_id_schema(self):
        return{
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "date": {"type": "string"},
                        "images": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "description": {"type": "string"},
                        "published": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "entity_id": {"type": "integer"},
                        "deleted": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "price": {"type": "integer"},
                        "control_stock": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "name": {"type": "string"},
                        "id": {"type": "integer"},
                        "time": {"type": "string"},
                        "stock": {"type": "integer"},
                        "category": {"type": "string"}
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "date",
                        "images",
                        "description",
                        "published",
                        "entity_id",
                        "deleted",
                        "price",
                        "control_stock",
                        "name",
                        "id",
                        "time",
                        "stock",
                        "category"
                    ]
                },
                "message": {"type": "string"},
                "status": {"type": "string"}
            },
            "required": [
                "data",
                "message",
                "status"
            ]
        }
```

```py
import json
import requests
import jsonschema
class TestIdentifyById:
    def get_test_identify_by_id_schema(self):
        return {
            "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "date": {"type": "string"},
                        "images": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "description": {"type": "string"},
                        "published": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "entity_id": {"type": "integer"},
                        "deleted": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "price": {"type": "integer"},
                        "control_stock": {"type": "boolean"},
                        "name": {"type": "string"},
                        "id": {"type": "integer"},
                        "time": {"type": "string"},
                        "stock": {"type": "integer"},
                        "category": {"type": "string"}
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "date",
                        "images",
                        "description",
                        "published",
                        "entity_id",
                        "deleted",
                        "price",
                        "control_stock",
                        "name",
                        "id",
                        "time",
                        "stock",
                        "category"
                    ]
                },

                "message": {"type": "string"},
                "status": {"type": "string"}
            },

            "required": [
                "data",
                "message",
                "status"
            ]
        }
```

El método es el siguiente:

```py
def test_identify_by_id_schema(self, variables):
    id = "30"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": variables["authorization"],
        "related-entity": "2"
    }

    response = requests.get (
        f"{variables['base_url']}/europa/product/{id}",
        headers = headers
    )

    assert response.status_code == 200 #400
    assert response.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json"

    response_body = response.json()

    jsonschema.validate(instance=response_body, schema=self.get_test_identify_by_id_schema())
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: como puedo hacer para que me deje de generar el error 400 (bad request)

Comment: Si el servidor te devuelve un error 400, es que la petición que estás realizando no es válida por alguna razón. Deberías mirar quizás en el lado del servidor qué petición está llegando, a ver si es que falta alguna cabecera o qué. También podrías comparar con algún ejemplo que tengas de petición válida realizada desde alguna otra vía (desde el navegador, o usando postman, etc). También podrías probar a imprimir la respuesta completa del servidor. Quizás a pesar del codigo 400 en el cuerpo de la respuesta vaya algún mensaje que aclare el error.

Comment: Y por cierto ¿qué se supone que es el código que has puesto en el primer y en el segundo recuadro de código? ¿Son idénticos? (aparentemente sí)